# How to compare two tensors of different shapes in one pass at a same time in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
>> A = tf.Tensor([4135047. 1193752.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
>> B = tf.Tensor(
          [1226019. 4135047. 4135047. 4169911. 1193752. 4135047. 4135047. 4135047.],
          shape=(8,), dtype=float32
       )

>> compare_1 = tf.math.equal(B, A[0])
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False False  True  True  True], shape=(8,), dtype=bool)

>> compare_2 = tf.math.equal(B, A[1])
tf.Tensor([False False False False  True False False False], shape=(8,), dtype=bool)

# final results
>> tf.math.logical_or(compare_1, compare_2)
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True  True  True], shape=(8,), dtype=bool)
```

What I want is to compare two tensors of different shape in one pass without using `tf.map()` function.

More precisely, I would like to compare each element of `tensor B` with all elements of `tensor A`. Result should be set to True if any element from `tensor A` matches with the element that we are comparing from `tensor B`

Expected outcome:

```py
>> compare(B, A)
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True  True  True])

# logic:
- 1st element from B, 1226019 doesn't match with any elements of A => False
- 2nd element from B, 4135047 match with an element in A => True
...
...
...
```

It looks like [tf.math.equal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/equal) can't compare two tensors of different shapes so right now I have to compare it in n-pass (for each element of tensor A) with tensor B and then apply the `logical_or()` on those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase your question (in a way that I find more understandable), it seems that you want a 1-D tensor with the same length as B, whose elements are `True` if the corresponding element of `B` appears in `A` and false otherwise.

Assuming I've understood correctly, here's one way to get this result. Note that because I replaced `logical_or` with `reduce_any`, this approach can be applied arrays `A` and `B` of arbitrary length. Note that this only works when `A` and `B` are one dimensional arrays.

```
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.constant([4135047., 1193752.])
B = tf.constant([1226019., 4135047., 4135047., 4169911., 1193752., 4135047., 4135047., 4135047.])

m = len(A)
n = len(B)
result = tf.math.reduce_any(
    tf.math.equal(
        tf.broadcast_to(A[:,None],[m,n]),tf.broadcast_to(B,[m,n])
    ), axis = 0
)
print(result)
```

The result:

```
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True  True  True], shape=(8,), dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben! It works as intended.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let me know if you have any questions about how this script works. If you're not familiar with `broadcast_to`, I recommend checking what the matrices `tf.broadcast_to(A[:,None],[m,n])` and `tf.broadcast_to(B,[m,n])` look like

Comment: Yes, I was dissecting that operation and I think it's a very clever way to use `broadcast_to` to convert tensors in same shape! Again, appreciate the answer!

Comment: Glad you think so :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, there's no difference in what it does. But you can have the code a lot cleaner than the other answer.

```
c = tf.math.reduce_any(B[:, None]==A[None, :], axis=1)
```

returns,

```
tf.Tensor([False  True  True False  True  True  True  True], shape=(8,), dtype=bool)
```